# How can I replace values of Javascript Object with different values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I'm looking for replacing the initial values of myObject by renamed names:

```js
let myObject = 
  [ { name: 'X0', values: 'FALSE,TRUE'      } 
  , { name: 'X1', values: 'NORMAL,LOW,HIGH' } 
  , { name: 'X2', values: 'HIGH,NORMAL,LOW' } 
  , { name: 'X3', values: 'FALSE,TRUE'      } 
  ]
```

I have two arrays: `arr1` contains all the unique values of `myObject`. `arr2` contains all the unique values renamed in which the values of `myObject` should be replaced.
As you can notice, they are already in the right order:
it means `FALSE` goes to `JDIFS`, `LOW` to `T9SQK` and so on.

```js
let arr1 = ['FALSE', 'TRUE',  'NORMAL', 'LOW',   'HIGH'  ]
let arr2 = ['JDIFS', 'CZ899', 'YVI0T',  'T9WQK', '0XCH7' ]
```

Output expected :

```js
let expected = 
  [ { name: 'X0', values: 'JDIFS,CZ899'        } 
  , { name: 'X1', values: 'YVIOT,TW9WQK,0XCH7' } 
  , { name: 'X2', values: '0XCH7,YVIOT,T9WQK'  } 
  , { name: 'X3', values: 'JDIFS,CZ899'        } 
  ]
```

I wanted to loop over the object like this:

```js
let second_column = myObject["columns"][1] 
for (let i=0; i< myObject.length; i++) {
  let tran = myObject[i][second_column].split(',') 
  // and perform and exchange with the two arrays I already have, or with the replace method
}
```

Comment: `myObject`, `arr1` and `arr2` always have same length ?

Comment: myObject no, arr1 and arr2, yes, always.

Comment: even though I'm not sure to get what you mean by myObject lenght, are you refering to the keys, values...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
let myObject = [
  { name: 'X0', values: 'FALSE,TRUE' },
  { name: 'X1', values: 'NORMAL,LOW,HIGH' },
  { name: 'X2', values: 'HIGH,NORMAL,LOW' },
  { name: 'X3', values: 'FALSE,TRUE' },
];

const arr1 = ['FALSE', 'TRUE', 'NORMAL', 'LOW', 'HIGH'];
const arr2 = ['JDIFS', 'CZ899', 'YVI0T', 'T9WQK', '0XCH7'];

for (let i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
  let tran = myObject[i].values;
  for (let j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    tran = tran.replace(arr1[j], arr2[j]);
  }
  myObject[i].values = tran;
}

console.log("OUTPUT:", myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```js
const myObject = [{"name":"X0","values":"FALSE,TRUE"},{"name":"X1","values":"NORMAL,LOW,HIGH"},{"name":"X2","values":"HIGH,NORMAL,LOW"},{"name":"X3","values":"FALSE,TRUE"}];
const arr1 = ["FALSE", "TRUE", "NORMAL", "LOW", "HIGH"];
const arr2 = ["JDIFS", "CZ899", "YVI0T", "T9WQK", "0XCH7"]
const result = myObject.map( i => {
   const data = i.values.split(',').map(val => arr2[arr1.indexOf(val)]);
   return {
    ...i,
    values: data.join(',')
   }
})
console.log(result)
```

> i.values.split(','): "FALSE,TRUE" => ["FALSE","TRUE"]

> arr2[arr1.indexOf(val)]: return value by index

Comment: `myObject.map(obj=>({...obj, values:obj.values.split(',').map(val => arr2[arr1.indexOf(val)]).join(',') }))`

Comment: @Pighead: please add some explanation to your answer, explaining how your code solves the problem